# overload method not getting called in cast operator overload

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, polymorphism

I have a base class that includes a `virtual` method and a cast operator:

```
class Base {
public:
    Base() {}
    operator int() const { return getInt(); }
protected:
    virtual int getInt() const { return 0; }
}
```

Then I have two derived classes that override the virtual method:

```
class Derived1 {
public:
    Derived1() : Base() {}
protected:
    virtual int getInt() const override { return 1; }
}

class Derived2 {
public:
    Derived2() : Base() {}
protected:
    virtual int getInt() const override { return 2; }
}
```

Then I have a helper function:

```
Base helper(const bool flag) {
    if (flag)
        return Derived1();
    else
        return Derived2();
}
```

The intention of that helper function is to be used like:

```
int one = helper(true); // I expect "one" to be 1
int two = helper(false); // I expect "two" to be 2
```

But both `one` and `two` contain `0`. I have no idea how to resolve this. Is the cast operator getting called before the `Derived` classes are fully constructed? My environment is VS2013.

---

**Suggested fix (in my case, after answers)**

I ended up turning the `helper` function into a `class` which stores `Derived`s as members and returning a reference to them (which I believe is actually a better design since on each `[]` call a `Derived` does not get constructed / allocated):

```
class Helper {
public:
    Helper();
    const Base& get(const bool flag) const {
        if (flag)
            return mDerived1;
        else
            return mDerived2;
    }
private:
    Derived1    mDerived1;
    Derived2    mDerived2;
}
```

---

**Side note**

Accepted answer suggests that the gist of the question is thinking about everything as in references (like Python) and that is true. This issue came up as a part of a bigger system design which allows access to results returning from a SQLite database with a Python like syntax in C++. Chaining square brackets like: `mData[0][1]`.

Comment: did you mean `helper` instead of `Base` when you call `(true)` or `(false)`?

Comment: You return type is `Base`. It is a `Base` object. There is no mystery there.

Comment: you should be returning `int` instead

Comment: So I MUST return the derived type? But that defeats the purpose of polymorphism then.

Comment: No, you just need to learn how polymorphism works in C++.

Comment: @3p3r maybe you [meant this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a5f6aac638b752a7) ?

Comment: @PiotrS. Except that will leak instances (you have no `delete` to correspond to your `new`s).

Comment: @cdhowie you don't leak memory when program exits

Comment: @PiotrS. That's about the worst imaginable defense for writing code like that. You are teaching bad practices and your defense is "it won't cause problems in this case." Smart pointers exist for a reason.

Comment: @cdhowie I'm not teaching anythning, I am presenting a concept asking if this is what OP aims to achieve.

Comment: @cdhowie you suggest smart pointers in comments below, but I can't see you suggesting using the virtual destructor, does that mean you teach not to use virtual destructors when using inheritance? see what I mean now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `helper` function returns `Base` by value, which slices off any derived-ness of the object you created inside the function, causing the virtual method to call the base version.

EDIT: I saw this had been marked duplicate but the duplicate, while explaining the problem, doesn't seem to clearly provide a nice solution to this specific problem.

The gist of the answer is that you're probably used to a language like Python or Java where everything is references (and I make the opposite mistake when using those languages). In C++ everything is by value unless you specify everything, and when returned by value the slicing problem comes forward.

What you want to do is allocate the appropriate derived type on the heap, and return a smart pointer to that object from your `helper` function. The smart pointer will make sure you don't leak memory, and by returning as a pointer instead of by value, you make sure that polymorphism is still active in your program.

Comment: is there a solution to it? if I make `getInt` in `Base` pure virtual that gives me a compile error which is expected. I have tons of those Derived classes in my code.

Comment: You'd have to return an `std::unique_ptr<Base>` for example, then do `int one = *(helper(true));`. You can only be polymorphic with pointers and references, not with values.